# pip install でクロスプラットフォーム用のライブラリを生成したい

Tags: python, pip, aws-lambda

lambda_function.py に

```
import pyorc
```

とかいて AWS Lambda にデプロイしたところ
`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyorc._pyorc'`
となってしまいます

```
mkdir src
cp lambda_funvtion.py src/
cd src; pip install pyorc --target .
```

であとは sam コマンドで src ディレクトリをコード指定してデプロイしました

pip install で生成された コードを見ると全部 python ではなく
/pyorc/_pyorc.cpython-37m-darwin.so
というのがあってこれが MAC 用のバイナリで Lambda 環境で動かないせいかと思っています

pip install でクロスプラットフォーム用のバイナリを生成する方法はありませんか？

Comment: 参考: [コンパイルされたバイナリを含む Python パッケージをデプロイパッケージに追加し、Lambda と互換性を持たせる](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/)

Comment: 教えていただいた方法で動作させることができました！